# Python Newbie : How to print exception log to a file

Tags: python

I am a newbie at Python and trying to write a small program to put the exeception stack to a file. Could someone let me know why the below code is not printing the whole stack into the file. :

```
import logging

import traceback

def divlog(x,y):
    try:
        f = open("C:/files/divlog.txt", "a")
        f.write("{0:g} / {1:g} = {2:g} \n".format(x, y , (x/y) ) )
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        #f.write("Error : \n" , traceback.format_exc())
           raise 
    finally:
        f.close()

divlog(100,21)
divlog(20,5)
divlog(10, 0)
divlog(100,spam)
```

Comment: You might want to consider the [logging](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html) module to avoid having to open a file each time you reach a similar situation, and in general to make the logging code cleaner and more systematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your `open` shouldn't be inside the `try..except` for a `ZeroDivisionError`. Best solution try using a `with` statement instead, to automatically close the file.

```
with open("C:/files/divlog.txt", "a") as f:
    try:
        f.write("{0:g} / {1:g} = {2:g} \n".format(x, y , (x/y) ) )
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        f.write("Error : \n" + traceback.format_exc())  # <-- write takes 1 arg
        raise
```

Everything else looks right. Most likely you're getting an `OSError` from trying to open the file, and it's not caught by your `except ZeroDivisionError`

Answer (score 1):

While not really answering your question as such, you can make two very easy improvment to your code that will bypass your problem:

First, you should use the [Python logging module](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/logging.html) as there should be no need to re-invent the wheel.  Python comes with batteries so use them!

Second, you should consider using the `with X as Y` code structure for opening files:

```
with open(file) as fd:
    fd.write("ook")
```

This will ensure that the file gets closed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Python have a module called sys, in which sys.stdout and sys.stderr can be helpful to log into another file

```
import logging
import sys
import traceback

f= open("C:\\AllReleases\\divlog1.txt", "a")
sys.stdout = f
sys.stderr = f
def divlog(x,y):
    try:

       f.write("{0:g} / {1:g} = {2:g} \n".format(x, y , (x/y) ) )
    except ZeroDivisionError:
       f.write("Error : \n" , traceback.format_exc())
       raise
```

divlog(10, 0)
divlog(100,21)
divlog(20,5)
divlog(100,spam)

f.close()

This will open  file and write the run and error details in the given file divlog1.txt

Answer (score 0):

This seems like exactly what the python [logging](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module is for.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',
                    level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def divlog(x,y):
    try:
        logger.info("{0:g} / {1:g} = {2:g} \n".format(x, y, x/y))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        logger.exception("There was a division by zero")

def main():
    divlog(100,21)
    divlog(20,5)
    divlog(10, 0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This gives you a file "example.log" with the following in it

```
INFO:__main__:100 / 21 = 4 

INFO:__main__:20 / 5 = 4 

ERROR:__main__:There was a division by zero
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in divlog
    logger.info("{0:g} / {1:g} = {2:g} \n".format(x, y, x/y))
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

We're taking advantage of the logging.exception function to capture the traceback and log it to the file for us. Take a look at the [Official HowTo](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging) for more details and examples.